# Has AP published DOJ memo regarding sedition statute?

Tags: united-states, justice-department

In a story titled *[Justice Dept.: Sedition charge may apply to protest violence](https://apnews.com/cbca8672a70f9f170a086a7a252a751e)* the Associated  Press (AP) says it has obtained a DOJ memo regarding the potential of applying federal "Seditious Conspiracy" statute: [18 U.S.C. § 2384](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2384).   Has the AP, or any other organization, published the actual memo?

The story starts out saying:

> WASHINGTON (AP) — *In a memo to U.S. attorneys Thursday obtained by The Associated Press*, the Justice Department emphasized that federal prosecutors should aggressively go after demonstrators who cause violence — and even sedition charges could potentially apply.

Has anyone been able to locate a verbatim copy of the DOJ memo cited?

If not, why would the AP not publish it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AP doesn't appear to have published Thursday's memo, sent by deputy attorney general Jeffrey A. Rosen, verbatim, however it appears to be freely [available to view and download](https://www.justice.gov/opa/page/file/1317916/) on the DOJ's own website.

To quote the relevant part of the memo:

> The Attorney General and I recently discussed with you the need to
> consider the use of a variety of federal charges when they may be
> appropriate, including "Seditious conspiracy" under 18 U.S.C. § 2384.
> I want to re-emphasize that message. As was previously pointed out,
> Section 2384 does not require proof of a plot to overthrow the U.S.
> Government, despite what the name might suggest. As the Attorney
> General noted in our discussion with you, it also applies to
> conspiracies with any of the following objects:
>
> - "to oppose by force
>   the authority [of the Government of the United States]";
> - "by force to prevent, hinder, or delay the execution of any law of the United States";
>   or
> - "by force to seize, take, or possess any property of the United
>   States contrary to the authority thereof."